# Is it possible to mitigate CVE-2016-5696 using a perimeter firewall?

Tags: iptables, firewall, tcp

The Linux kernel vulnerability CVE-2016-5696 disclosed last week affects a lot of devices, and a network administrator may not have root access to all of them (if owned by customer, or in the case of Android, root is held by the manufacturer and not the owner).  It's unreasonable to think that patches will be coming anytime soon for all of these devices, and without root it isn't even possible to increase the global rate limit to mitigate the side channel.

However, the attack relies on the attacker being able to intentionally trigger a number of challenge-ACK packets back to themselves, in order to see whether the one on the spoofed connection causes the limit to be reached.  If a border firewall were to restrict the number of challenge-ACK packets returning to an attacker to a lower number than the limit on the device being attacked, the information leak would be plugged.

For example, if a vulnerable device has a default global rate limit of 100, then implementing a per-node rate limit of 20 at a border router would prevent an outside attacker from executing the off-path attack, even if the device and firewall clock are not synchronized (best attacker can do is 20 at the end of one second followed immediately by 40 in the next, far short of the 100 that the attacked device is configured to send).  Local devices could still communicate without being affected by the rate limit.

How would one implement such a mitigation using iptables on a Linux firewall running kernel version 4.x?  What packets should be matched, what modules would keep track of the per-node rate and allow limiting?

Is it possible to detect an ongoing attack by counting challenge ACK packets (does the firewall have enough information to distinguish them?) and then blackhole the attacker?  (This probably could not be accomplished using iptables alone, but using a reactive rule generator)

Detecting challenge-ACK packets may be a prerequisite, in order to not throttle ACK packets coming from the true peer.

Comment: Why not just update kernel?

Comment: @Alexus Maybe I missed something, how does updating the kernel on the router protect the many other devices for which there are binary driver blobs that will not work with a brand new kernel? (not to mention Tivoization where a new kernel can be installed only with a vendor signature)

Comment: This is pretty much just a server-side vulnerability.  Fix the servers and you're done.

Comment: "which makes it easier for **man-in-the-middle** attackers to hijack TCP sessions" - That mean they must be in the middle, thus in your perimeter already. Do you trust your LAN user? For android device on LTE connection its another story

Comment: @yagmoth555: If you even looked at the title of [the paper](http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~zhiyunq/pub/sec16_TCP_pure_offpath.pdf), you would know this is an **Off-Path** attack, not limited to local attackers.

Comment: @DerfK: Even it did only affect the server-side, all kinds of small Linux appliances are running HTTP and other servers.  TCP servers are not limited to the rack-mounted computers you call "servers".

Comment: I think security.stackexchange.com might be better suited for this question.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: Yeah right after posting this I realized there are probably two components: Developing the packet-filtering criteria, better suited for IT Security StackExchange, and actually deploying using a real implementation like iptables, which belongs here.

Comment: @BenVoigt Form the paper: " victim client, a victim server and an off-
path attacker"   and "Alternatively, as shown in Figure 2,
the off-path attacker is able to send packets to the client
with **the spoofed IP address of the victim server.**"  Tell me how a external user can spoof an internal IP when the connection is done inside your LAN ?  The problem affect mostly server like DerfK told for that reason.

Comment: @yagmoth555: Read more closely.  There's routing going on between the client and server; when the attacker spoofs the server's address, it comes through the border router to the client, just like legitimate data from the real server.

Comment: @yagmoth555: The "network" depicted as a cloud in Figure 2 is the entire Internet, not a LAN.

Comment: You are right if your router don't NAT, else modern router block non routable IP coming from the WAN link and without a forward rule external packet will be blocked at the router. Thats why I found the bug more big for phone & server facing the internet

Comment: @yagmoth555: Yes, this question is talking about routers between public IP networks, not NAT.  Most NAT routers won't protect against this though, because the spoofed packet matches a real connection except for sequence number, the NAT will translate it.  NAT would interfere with the other connection needed for the attack, though, the one the attack makes without spoofing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure how realistic it is to worry about this vulnerability in a managed network for a few reasons I can think of.

- When Bob brings his vulnerable Android phone into work and connects to the corporate WiFi, his phone isn't publically accessible so no outside actor can send him packets to try and trigger challenge ACKs.*
- The corporate Network is very likely to be using NAT at the perimeter preventing any funky spoofed IP packets from leaving the network. Even without NAT, spoofed IP packets should not be leaving the network.

*It is of course still possible that Bob tries to DoS devices on the LAN however that traffic won't be traversing the firewall anyway.

Worth nothing that Challenge ACKs are just ACKs with specific Sequence Numbers so you would likely need to implement custom tracking/packet parsing on your Firewall to pick them out. That sounds pretty pants.

Comment: The problem is with spoofed packets *entering* the network, not leaving.  I'm trying to help a wireless ISP solve this, where the customer nodes do receive public IPs (most customers use NAT on their own premises, but the consumer NAT/router devices are among the vulnerable nodes)  Lots of university networks are going to be facing this as well, because they have large numbers of devices with routable IPs administered by many different departments and groups.

Comment: Ok, if the devices are actually exposed to this vulnerability and you cannot patch them, then it sounds like you are on the right track. Perhaps even a simple RST rate limit per source IP would be sufficient.

Comment: RFC 5961 specifies that challenge ACK is generated in response to both out-of-order SYN and RST.  But if you could show how to implement the per-source RST-only rate limit, that would be awesome (and a checkmark).

Answer (score 0):

**Is it possible to mitigate CVE-2016-5696 using a perimeter firewall?**

Probably not.  At least, I would not expect any firewall vendors to officially support a form of mitigation against this.  There are far too many scenerios where false positives would result in legit traffic being blocked.

The best you could likely do is update a config on your servers, or run one command at startup until you have a patched kernel.  The vulnerability is due to Linux confirming to an RFC that nobody else conformed to.

To negate this behavior, update all of your servers `/etc/sysctl.conf` with:

```
net.ipv4.tcp_challenge_ack_limit = 131070
```

Then run `sysctl -e -p` on all of the servers you applied this setting to.

If you plan on updating your kernel soon, you could simply run:

```
sysctl -w "net.ipv4.tcp_challenge_ack_limit=131070"
```

so that you do not need to change configuration files.

Why 131070?  Anything over 1000 would suffice if the kernel was updated with randomization.  The patch to the kernel sets the number to 1000 and adds randomization to mitigate the attack scenerio.  Without the randomizion, you want a much larger number.  I've seen some folks using 9 million.

[ Update ] To sum up:  Based on your comments, a perimeter firewall would not likely help you.   A perimeter layer 4 proxy would.  I would seriously read up on haproxy.

Comment: That's unfortunate, because many devices will be patched *never*, due to Tivoization,  The keys needed to sign update binaries may even have been lost.

Comment: That is indeed unfortunate.  That said, if your traffic is terminated on a load balancer that is not vulnerable, or by haproxy servers that are not vulnerable, then I would be far less concerned.

Comment: This isn't a server farm, it's a bunch of devices like wireless PtP links, which have TCP listeners.  Running firmware based on Linux but with lots of vendor-provided customizations, and the vendors are unlikely to provide patches for all the different models in any sort of timely fashion, if ever.

Comment: So to answer your question, perimeter firewall = no, perimeter layer 4 proxy, yes.  haproxy would do the trick.